# Phonegap 2.9.0 error:deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0

Tags: ios, cordova

When building facebook demo app. I am getting console output  like this.

```
    2013-09-23 14:02:36.548 Phonegapfbdemo[3708:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
    2013-09-23 14:02:38.532 Phonegapfbdemo[3708:c07] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2013-09-23 14:02:40.173 Phonegapfbdemo[3708:c07] DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release. 
    2013-09-23 14:02:40.813 Phonegapfbdemo[3708:c07] Finished load of: file:///Users/chintanshah/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/60F4DA36-DB97-49D0-81B4-719335C74203/Phonegapfbdemo.app/www/index.html
```

if any body has solved this issue. plz help me

here is my code:

config.xml

```
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
    </feature>`enter code here`
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="ios-package"  value="CDVFile"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVBattery"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVEcho"/>
    </feature>

    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Logger">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

and my index.html looks like

```
 <div id="deviceready"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
  <script src="js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
  <!-- facebook js sdk -->  
  <script src="js/facebook_js_sdk.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/_config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
  <script src="js/feed.js"></script>
  <script src="js/graph_api.js"></script>
  <script src="js/requests.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="js/credits.js"></script>-->

  <script>
      // Initialize the Facebook SDK
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
          FB.init({
              appId: '177390275777596',
              nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
              useCachedDialogs: false
          });

          FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);

          authUser();
          updateAuthElements();
      });
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: hi @amit here am editing some code

Comment: i means i want to see your /index.html

Comment: Hi @amit This issue occurs in ios

Comment: no worries finally i solved my problem

Comment: Actually where is the problem in fb integration or any othere

Comment: that issue was occured in  java scripting.

Comment: How did you solved it can you post your solution.

Comment: I am stuck into it. If your solution could help me.

Comment: which type error you geeting .can you please share error

Comment: Hi @sanjay I am getting the same type of error.                     DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release.                                       Can you please post the solution.

Comment: @ Vaishali Modi could you please share your index html code with me according to that i will check issue